# Not able to import speech_recognition using python 2.6

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am not able to import speech_recognition module using python 2.6 on Centos 6.5. I have installed SpeechRecognition using pip and it installed successfully without any errors.

```
pip install SpeechRecognition

Downloading SpeechRecognition-3.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31.8MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 31.8MB 14kB/s 
Installing collected packages: SpeechRecognition
Successfully installed SpeechRecognition-3.6.5
```

But Somehow I am not able to import it.

```
>>> import speech_recognition
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 1070
if system == "Windows" and machine in {"i686", "i786", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"}:
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: edit `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py"` file and change `if system == "Windows" and machine in {"i686", "i786", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"}:` to `if system == "Windows" and machine in ("i686", "i786", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"):`

Comment: It looks like the problem is that it's using set literal syntax, which is only valid in Python 2.7+ and 3.x. Can understand your confusion, though, as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/ claims to support Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition

Comment: Please don't write code-only answers, try to explain what you're doing.